# Always boot in Safe Mode but Shift key is Normal

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I'm desperate, as my 2010 13” MBP A1278 always boots to Safe Mode. I tried checking the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, but it's normal.  I have no idea how could this happen.

Please help me, if anyone have ever experienced this problem.

Actually I plan to reinstall the High Sierra, but as it always behaving as if the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed, then while I tried to press <kbd>Option</kbd>key it just boots normally.  It’s just I can’t boot from an external USB or other way to install.

Comment: How did you determine the Shift key was working?  Also, keep in mind there are two Shift keys.  Do both work?

Comment: Sorry for my poor english

Comment: I checked using system preference "keyboard" and all keys work fine, including both shift keys and also caps lock key. Also when typing, never experience any problem

Comment: Try a PRAM reset.